# PHP loop rating bar error

Tags: php, loops, rating-system

I have a 5 point rating system I am trying to change up how it displays the rating.

So before it would be 5 dots all white if not rated, then color in the ratings blue.. I would display these dots via fontawesome glyphs. So it would output 5 of them.

But now i'm trying to change it where the 5 point rating would display a progress bar and the 5 points be used as percentages for the length of progress.

Sorry if i am vague, I can explain more if needed. It currently displays all the bars and rating values, but just once. So it's not functioning the way I want it to.

```
<?php if(count($languages) > 0) { ?>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="no-bullets">

    <?php foreach($languages as $index => $language) { ?>

        <li>
            <span class="skillset-title"><?= $language->title; ?> (<?= $language->endorsement; ?>)</span>
            <span class="skillset-rating">

            <?php
            $levelpercentage = 0;
            for($stars == 1; $stars <= 5; $stars++) {

                if ($stars == 5):

                    echo $levelpercentage = 100;

                elseif ($stars == 4):

                    echo $levelpercentage = 80;

                elseif ($stars == 3):

                    echo $levelpercentage = 60;

                elseif ($stars == 2):

                    echo $levelpercentage = 40;

                elseif ($stars == 1):

                    echo $levelpercentage = 20;

                endif;

            ?>

                <div class="progress-bar blue stripes">
                    <span style="width: <?= ($language->level >= $stars) ? $levelpercentage : '0'; ?>%;"></span>
                </div>

            <?php  } ?>

            </span>
        </li>

        <?php if(ceil(count($languages) / 2) == $index + 1) { ?>

    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="no-bullets">

        <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>

    </ul>
</div>

<?php } else { ?>

<div class="alert alert-warning">
    No languages were found!
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> It currently displays all the bars and rating values

That's because you assign and echo your bars and rating values in a `for` loop.

Your `$stars` variable is assigned every value from 1 to 5, displaying the bar at each step. Simply remove your `for` loop and it should work fine (provided you use an already defined `$stars` variable)

Bonus : Because I'm in a good mood, I have to tell you there's a simpler way to build your `$levelpercentage` variable than using an `if...else` for each value from 1 to 5, just use :

```
$levelpercentage = $stars * 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! That really helped me out. Was trying to simplify what I was trying to do. This is what I did and it seems to be working.

```
<?php if(count($languages) > 0) { ?>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="no-bullets">

    <?php foreach($languages as $index => $language) { $stars = 0; $stars <= 5; $stars++; ?>

        <li>
            <span class="skillset-title"><?= $language->title; ?> (<?= $language->endorsement; ?>)</span>
            <span class="skillset-rating">
                 <div class="progress-bar blue stripes">
                     <span style="width: <?= ($language->level >= $stars) ? $language->level * 20 : 0; ?>%;"></span>
                 </div>
            </span>
        </li>

        <?php if(ceil(count($languages) / 2) == $index + 1) { ?>

    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="no-bullets">

        <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>

    </ul>
</div>

<?php } else { ?>

<div class="alert alert-warning">
    No languages were found!
</div>

<?php } ?>
```